# Binary Cross Entropy Loss for Image Segmentation

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am using a CNN (U-Net) in Keras to segment an 8 bit image to get a binary mask. Despite reaching an accuracy of 0.9999 I still get a few values that are between 0 and 255 but would like to completely remove these values to have only 0 or 255. I have so far been using the binary cross entropy loss function, combined with a sigmoid activation function the last convolutional layer. Can someone tell me if there are other loss functions that could possibly solve this problem.

Comment: Can you explain you're net a bit more? What is the shape of your output? What are your labels? Do you have labels for your binary mask, whichs eems to be not your current output?

Answer (score 1):

its better to use values between 0 - 1 .

its much harder do the NN to get good result at 0-255 , this way the  binary cross entropy will work much better

Comment: I'm very confused about this point because he stated that he already use sigmoid activation function which produce a output between 0 and 1

Comment: your output will be between 0 - 1 but your input will stay at 0 - 255 and its doing lots of problems in image recognition and this kind of fields. without normalization you will have a big value at the nodes and only at the end it will turn into 0 or 1 so it will be really hard for the model to produce real result

Comment: Yes but it seems that the output is between 0 and 255, which makes no sense if he uses sigmoid. You're right about normalization (something like equal frequency binning might work even better)

Comment: My input image pixel values are indeed either 0 for background or 255 for signal of interest, but I divide all pixel values by 255 before loading the training data.

Answer (score 0):

You can threshold to get only the two values you want. E.g:

```
y = model.predict(input_image) # your result image
y = 255 * (y > 128)
```

Comment: I was considering this, but just wanted to know if there are perhaps other options as well. Thanks!

Comment: You can use dice loss, which produces almost exactly binary images or threshold as observed in this work (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04117.pdf)